# Error Message = Listener refused the connection with the following error

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to open sql developer application in C:\oracle19_c\WINDOWS.X64_193000_db_home\sqldeveloper\sqldeveloper\bin\sql.exe in that it is asking about the username and password I have no idea what username and password I have to give. And if I tried username and password I get the error as below .

error:'  URL= jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/xe
Error Message = Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12514, TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor

Could anyone pls help me with this issue.

Comment: I was going to point you to [this classic blog post](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2012/12/i-have-oracle-sql-developer-installed-now-what/); but from the path you do have Oracle installed. So, have you created and started a database, or have you just installed the server software? (You might still want to download the latest SQL Developer anyway - not sure what version ships with 19.3.)

Comment: @AlexPoole in that version they have access to the command-line version of SQLDev, aka SQLcl.. PS Classic post? Thanks :)

Comment: thank you alex, as you mentioned in first post I have installed the latest version of sql developer but the sql developer 21.c application is not at all opening it is always on loading page

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.